# how can I change the UISegmented Control title color

Tags: ios, title, uisegmentedcontrol

There is an UISegmentedControl in the xib file, I want to change the title color when selected, how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this in (iOS 5 and later) is with `-setTitleTextAttributes: forState:`.

Example:
`[segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:@{ UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor lightGrayColor] } forState:UIControlStateSelected];`

Documentation: [UISegmentedControl Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006807)